# iCal4j and using primefaces p.schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule, ical4j

I´m currently try to use ical4j and p:schedule

I´m generating my ical4j events as below:

```
public void createEvent(BookingDate bookingDate, Mandatory mandatory, Employee employee)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParserException, ConstraintViolationException {

    // Create a TimeZone
    System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

    TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
    TimeZone timezone = registry.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
    VTimeZone tz = timezone.getVTimeZone();

    String pathMandatoryFile = null;
    String pathEmployeeFile = null;

    // Reading the file and creating the calendar

    Calendar icsCalendar = null;


    if (bookingDate.isCreateCalendarMandatoryEntry()) {
        // timezone = registry.getTimeZone(mandatory.getTimeZone());

        pathMandatoryFile = mandatory.getDirectoryRootFolder();
        pathMandatoryFile = pathMandatoryFile + File.separator + ConstantsStorage.CALENDAR_FOLDER + File.separator
                + "calendar.ics";

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            icsCalendar = builder.build(fin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Wenn noch kein Kalender vorhanden, dann erstellen
        if (icsCalendar == null) {
            icsCalendar = createNewCalender(pathMandatoryFile);
        }
    }

    // Creating an event
    java.util.Calendar startCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, bookingDate.getStartDate().getYear());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, bookingDate.getStartDate().getMonth());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, bookingDate.getStartDate().getDate());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, bookingDate.getStartDate().getHours());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, bookingDate.getStartDate().getMinutes());
    startCal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, bookingDate.getStartDate().getSeconds());

    java.util.Calendar endCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, bookingDate.getEndDate().getYear());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, bookingDate.getEndDate().getMonth());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, bookingDate.getEndDate().getDate());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, bookingDate.getEndDate().getHours());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, bookingDate.getEndDate().getMinutes());
    endCal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, bookingDate.getEndDate().getSeconds());

    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime dtStart = new DateTime(startCal.getTime());
    dtStart.setTimeZone(timezone);


    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime dtEnd = new DateTime(endCal.getTime());
    dtEnd.setTimeZone(timezone);


    String eventName = bookingDate.getName();
    VEvent meeting = new VEvent(dtStart, dtEnd, eventName);

    // add timezone info..
    meeting.getProperties().add(tz.getTimeZoneId());
    String uidValue = bookingDate.getIdHash();
    meeting.getProperties().add(new Uid(uidValue));

    // Add the event and print
    icsCalendar.getComponents().add(meeting);

    CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(pathMandatoryFile);
    outputter.output(icsCalendar, fout);

}
```

My output in the .cal - File:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
```

PRODID:-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180830T200603Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180808T000000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180808T000000
SUMMARY:MegaTest
TZID:Europe/Berlin
UID:1535659563533-b091a66c-5a0e-4730-bba2-cf94e6763514
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180830T202034Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180806T000000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180806T000000
SUMMARY:dasas
TZID:Europe/Berlin
UID:1535660434464-3db07bd9-eff0-4c28-9178-5cca1be89e23
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180830T202245Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180830T230000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:01180830T231000
SUMMARY:Test
TZID:Europe/Berlin
UID:1535660565611-a9341234-5186-469e-9ad6-5b9c754221e7
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Now I´m trying to use p:schedule to show it in the schedule, but it´s not working (I guess due to the wrong date format for the p:schedule, because the list includes my events...)

Here my code for the Primefaces p:schedule:

```
public void loadAllEvents() {
    lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

        @Override
        public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {
            try {

                CalendarExtern calendarExtern = new CalendarExtern();
                calendarExtern.setSelectedForView(true);
                readFromFile(calendarExtern);


                SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

                net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar calendar = null;

                if (calendarExtern.getUrl() == null) {
                    calendar = bookingCalendarService.readCalenderFromFile(calendarExtern);
                }

                else {
                    calendar = bookingCalendarService.readCalenderFromUrl(calendarExtern);
                }

                for (Iterator i = calendar.getComponents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                    Component component = (Component) i.next();
                    // new event

                    // Date start = SDF.parse(component.getProperty("DTSTART").getValue());
                    // Date end = SDF.parse(component.getProperty("DTEND").getValue());

                    String startTime = component.getProperty(Property.DTSTART).getValue();
                    Date startDate = SDF.parse(startTime);

                    String endTime = component.getProperty(Property.DTEND).getValue();
                    Date endDate = SDF.parse(endTime);


                    String summary = component.getProperty("SUMMARY").getValue();

                    addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(summary, startDate, endDate));


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
}
```

What should I change to solve this?

Comment: You should (akways) start by narrowing down the problem. PF schedule nows nothing about ical. It is your code in between. Debug what values from the ical are used for the eventmodel and then try these as static values. Maybe you'll see something remarkable then...

Comment: And _"but it´s not working"_ is sort pf vague and _"(I guess due to the wrong date format for the p:schedule,...) "_ is exactly what my debugging suggestion is about... hint dtstart and end look strange... 0118?